# How to prevent repeated request from a server on website

Tags: security, ddos, server-side-attacks

Hello someone is trying to make multiple signups on my website with different IP what could be the easy way to prevent this . I am using aws stack for website hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply distinguish them because all requests are legitimate, or at least the attacker *can* make it look legitimate (e.g. innocent-looking user agents, etc.).

One common practice is to employ Captcha/reCaptcha so that bots can be blocked, but still it wouldn't work if the person is dedicated enough to solve them manually.